# Imprimir del 1 al 10 consecutivamente

Tags: python

Buen dia, estoy buscando imprimir 1 solo numero de rango del 1 al 10, Es parecido a imprimir 1 solo numero random, Pero no he logrado la forma de imprimir del 1 al 10 consecutivamente.

Se que para que obtener una lista de números consecutivos puedo usar un for con range o un list, Pero como imprimir del 1 hasta el numero final consecutivamente?

Si tengo ya una lista de numero consecutivos, Como podría imprimirlo consecutivamente?

esta es una forma de varias para obtener una lista.

```
list = []
calc = 1

while int(calc) < 9:
    list.append(calc)
    calc = int(calc) + 1

print(list)
```

Comment: No se si entendí bien, pero si tienes una lista de 10 numeros,lo que puedes hacer es mostrarlos ordenados, de la siguiente manera:   `sorted(list)`. Y si tienes numeros repetidos puedes hacer  `sorted(set(list))` para quitar los duplicados y mostrar los "únicos".

Comment: @LucasDamian Gracias por responder, Entiendo lo que me dices, Pero lo que yo busco es de por ejemplo una lista del 1 al 10, imprimir solo el 1, Luego en la siguiente impresion el 2, en la siguiente impresion el 3, y asi consecutivamente hasta el 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes

- Definir una variable con el valor inicial
- Usar un bucle `while` involucrando el número limite como condición, incrementarlo por cada ciclo.

---

**La función:**

```
i = 1

def sacarNumero():
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
```

**El botón de Tkinter:**

Haciendo uso del argumento `command`:

```
tk.Button(frame,text = "Sacar Número",command = sacarNumero)
```

Espero que te haya servido.

Comment: Muchas gracias es casi lo que busco, Sin embargo como podría usarlo en una Función para imprimir el numero +1 al clickear un boton.

Comment: Con botón te refieres a un botón de Tkinter o a qué?

Comment: Exacto, Ponerlo dentro de un def para usarlo en un boton de Tkinter

Comment: Checa mi respuesta, editada xD.

Comment: Me da los 10 números de una jaja :(

Comment: Perdón, error mió. Debes de definir i como global, fuera de la función. Si no me equivoca debería de funcionar, mira mi respuesta editada por tercera vez.

Comment: Esta vez me dio este error `local variable 'i' referenced before assignment`, Investigue y entendí que debia declarar que `i` existe fuera del `def ` para que pueda usarse, y tenia que declararlo dentro del `def` con un `Global i`, Pero de todas formas me sigue dando los 10 números de un click

Comment: Ya esta es la solución definitiva, quita el while. Como está en mi ejemplo editado por 4ta vez. Espero te sirva.

Comment: @Gabitohh Sigue faltando el `global i` al inicio de la función `sacarNumero()`

Answer (score 1):

Es evidente que para lograr que cada pulsación del botón saque un número diferente va a ser necesario guardar en alguna parte un contador, que registre cuántas veces se ha pulsado el botón.

Una solución puede ser hacer uso de una variable global, pero esto en general se considera mala práctica.

La otra opción es utilizar programación orientada a objetos y crear una clase `Contador`. La clase puede tener en un atributo el valor de la cuenta, y tener métodos que permitan manipular ese valor (por ejemplo, incrementarlo y volver a ponerlo a cero).

Si queremos que además de modificar el contador la clase lo muestre en la ventana Tk, será necesario que esa clase tenga acceso a una etiqueta de la ventana en la cual poder mostrarlo. De nuevo esa etiqueta podría ser una variable global, pero es mejor estilo que la etiqueta en cuestión se le pase al constructor del contador.

A continuación pongo una solución que hace uso de una clase como la descrita. De paso añado un botón para poder resetear el contador. En este ejemplo el valor del contador se muestra en la propia ventana (en vez de hacer un `print()` que lo mostraría por la consola).

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Ejemplo de contador")
window.geometry('120x50')

lbl = Label(window, text="0", width=5)  # Etiqueta para mostrar el valor del contador
lbl.grid(column=3, row=1)

# La clase que se ocupa de mantener y mostrar el valor de la cuenta
class Contador:
  def __init__(self, lbl:Label, init=0):
    self.c = init
    self.lbl:Label = lbl

  def next(self):
    self.c = self.c + 1
    self.lbl["text"] = str(self.c)

  def reset(self):
    self.c = 0
    self.lbl["text"] = str(self.c)

# Creamos una instancia del contador, pasándole como parámetro
# la etiqueta donde debe mostrar el resultado
cnt = Contador(lbl)

# Creamos un par de botones, uno para incrementar, otro para reiniciar
btn = Button(window, text="+1", command=cnt.next)
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)
btn = Button(window, text="Reset", command=cnt.reset)
btn.grid(column=3, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir tu lista tienes recorrerla elemento por elemento e imprimir

```
for i in list:
      print(i)
```

o

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
for x in range(len(list)):
          print list[x]
```

**EDIT:**

```
foo = 0
List = [1,2,3,4,5]
def nextOnList():
    if(foo < len(list)):
        foo +=1
        #Imprimes tu bendito numero
    else:
        foo = 0
        #ó
        foo -=1
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, Entiendo el codigo, Pero lo que yo busco es por ejemplo de una lista del 1 al 10, imprimir solo el 1, Luego en la siguiente impresión el 2, en la siguiente impresión el 3, y así consecutivamente hasta el 10

Comment: Ahhh venga, necesitas que se imprima de forma separada tipo `1 2 3 4 5`?

Comment: Lo que busco completamente es, Crear un boton que al momento de darle click me pase al siguiente numero ósea el 2, Luego clickear al boton de nuevo y  pase al siguiente numero el 3 y asi consecutivamente hasta el numero limite

Comment: Entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es una funcion como muestro en la respuesta. La edito.

Comment: Por alguna razon me da error de syntax en `nextOnList():
`

Comment: Una disculpa, esa línea iria así `def nextOnList():`

Comment: Disculpa amigo, No compredo el codigo jaja, Si pongo el Print fuera del def, Siempre me da 0, Pero si pongo el Print en el if no da ningún resultado

Answer (score 0):

Me da la impresión que lo que necesitas es usar un *generator*.

Un generator es una función que usa `yield` en lugar de `return`. Al usar yield, la función retorna el resultado pero sigue ejecutando como si nada hubiera pasado.

Para usar un generator debes escribir la función asi:

```
def fcn():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```

Luego, en tu programa, la conviertes en un iterador invocandola:

```
gen = fcn()
```

De ahi en adelante usas `gen` para obtener valores, no `fcn`.

El iterador (`gen` en este caso) se lo pasas a la función `next` cada vez que quieras obtener el siguiente número en la secuencia. Por ejemplo, para imprimir el siguiente valor, haces:

```
print(next(gen))
```

He aqui un ejemplo completo:

```
def fcn():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

# Crear el iterador    
gen = fcn()

# Recibes un click y llamas a la funciòn
print(next(gen))
# Recibes otro click
print(next(gen))
# y asi sucesivament
print(next(gen))
```

Ten siempre presente que `gen` lo usas como un iterador, que puede ser infinito o no. En este ejemplo, `fcn` cuenta hasta 10 y luego termina. Con eso ya no genera más números.

El generador puede tener paràmetros. Supon que quieres un generador más flexible, que te permita decir hasta donde contar. Este es el mismo ejemplo, ahora con limite:

```
def fcn(limite):
    for i in range(limite):
        yield i

# Crear el iterador con limite 20    
gen = fcn(20)

# Usarlo como iterador convencional
for i in gen:
    print(i)
```

Espero que sea lo que andas buscando. En todo caso, es una buena herramienta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder!, Es interesante. Sin embargo lo que busco es que el programa me dea el siguiente numero con dar 1 click en el botón en tkinter. Si le pongo un rango de 10. El primer click tiene que darme el 1, Luego otro click y me dea el 2 y así sucesivamente